# How to Communicate between two CORBA servers in java

Tags: java

i need to implement two java cobra servers
and these two servers needs to invoke function on each other.
i use this :

```
orb = ORB.init(args,null);
```

to initiate the orb for both client and server.
but when I invoke the function i get this error :

```
Dec 1, 2013 1:26:29 AM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.12.4; port: 51478"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
```

i guess i use the default setting for orb so when i use, since I have two orb only each of the server, so there may be conflicts.
need some help

Comment: Are you using a Name Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UDP to communicate between the two servers

Comment: Can you please expain about this? Or  any links about this topic?